# How to block some SMS, but only allow phone calls?

Tags: sms, calls

Hi I have a Samsung Galaxy 2S. How do I block SMS texts of my choice and only allow the phone calls? How do I block certain numbers from texting and not all of them, in other words, but allow the ones I'm blocking from sending me texts to call me instead if they so choose?

Comment: You can't prevent your phone from receiving texts except at the network level.  But you should be able to have them auto-deleted/ignored pretty easily at the user software level.  [What have you tried?](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=block%20sms&c=apps&hl=en)  "SMS Filter" is one of the top results for me and looks promising.

Comment: I use [**QKSMS**](https://github.com/moezbhatti/qksms) for SMS. I integrate QKSMS with [**Should I answer?**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mistergroup.muzutozvednout&hl=en). If I block number in Should I answer?, I not will receive SMS from this number too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking Contacts entirely is easily enough done. There is also SMS and call filtering applications that are free on the market- ESET AV is also a paid alternative. SMS filter and clean inbox are two alternatives for SMS blocking which both work quite well.

To combine both, there is a aFirewall SMS and call filter.  With many of these apps you're able to create set filers for calls, SMS or contacts to prevent them from bothering you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no blocking system built into the default messaging app. However, you can also block unwanted SMS or messages on your phone with other apps. There are already a few other apps here you've found. There is also the Google Messages app that you can find on the Google Play Store. By using this app, you can report any message as spam and it will be sent directly to the spam folder.